# Past Simple vs Present Perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-vs-present-perfect

> She has blushed after he pointed at her
>
> She blushed after he pointed at her

Do these sentences bear the same meaning?

**First:**

Does the first sentence mean that I can see the result right now? Does it mean that she blushed, for example, 20 seconds ago (just now)?

For example, I understand the first sentence as I was hanging out somewhere with a friend, then the action described above happens(the girl starts blushing), and my friend exclaims that she had blushed. Then I turn my head and I can see that she's red.

**Second:**

Does the second mean that the teller has a specific time in the past in his mind?

For example, it's more like a story that my friend would tell me, a story that took place at some point in the past, like 20 minutes ago or yesterday, or even one year ago.

**Question:**
Is my understanding of these sentences correct?

Answer (score 1):

She has blushed after he pointed at her.

She blushed after he pointed at her.

The first sentence is not grammatical, whereas the second sentence is OK

When you talk about two past related events, you use both the main clause and the "after clause" in the past tense.

Moreover, the simple past can also be used for recent action like the present perfect.

Comment: The first sentence is grammatical, it's just weird because we don't usually phrase things that way.  It's not necessarily a rule that you have to use the same tense in two clauses.

Comment: If I wrote: "_After he pointed at her, she has blushed_", it would not be correct, right? However, in my example the exact time goes in the second part of the sentence. Another example would be: "_I have already told you that (**pause here**) yesterday_" which is considered as a valid sentence in informal conversation. Am I right @stangdon ?

Comment: @vpaliyX - I don't know if "after he pointed at her, she has blushed" is *incorrect*, but it's so strange-sounding that I wouldn't use it.  ("*Since* he pointed at her, she has blushed" sounds good, though.)  "I have already told you that yesterday" might not be strictly grammatically correct (*yesterday* means it was in the past, but *I have* is a present tense), but it would be unremarkable in informal conversation.

Comment: @stangdon - Yeah, that's what I mean. In informal conversation we can get away with it: _I have already told you that ( then the teller pauses and recalls when did he say that/ or it just suddenly comes to mind) - yesterday._.  However, it's not correct to mention the time first, so that sentence will not be correct in reverse way.